# Get rows from MySQL table that have a column in common but slightly diffrent value

Tags: mysql, sql, linguistics

Might not even be a programming question, but the problem I'm having is I have a big MySQL table with products from different sources (stores) and in many cases it's the same product with different sources.

For example an "iPhone X":

```
+---------------------+-------+--------------+
| Title               | Price | Source       |
+---------------------+-------+--------------+
| iPhone X            | 1100  | Small Store  |
| iPhone X Phone      | 990   | Medium Store |
| Smartphone iPhone X | 990   | Big Store    |
| iPhone X Smartphone | 1000  | Extra Store  |
+---------------------+-------+--------------+
```

This is all the same product with different sources, but the `Title` is a bit different in each case.

What I want to do is when I `SELECT` one if them I want to return them all.

An idea that came to my head is calculating a hash based on something (the `Title`?) and storing that, like:

```
+---------------------+-------+--------------+----------+
| Title               | Price | Source       | Hash     |
+---------------------+-------+--------------+----------+
| iPhone X            | 1100  | Small Store  | SAMEHASH |
| iPhone X Phone      | 990   | Medium Store | SAMEHASH |
| Smartphone iPhone X | 990   | Big Store    | SAMEHASH |
| iPhone X Smartphone | 1000  | Extra Store  | SAMEHASH |
+---------------------+-------+--------------+----------+
```

That way when I'm fetching an "iPhone X" by something, like a slug `getProductsBySlug(slug string) []Product {}`, I can `SELECT` one of them, get the hash and find the rest.

Just not sure how I could calculate such a hash so it's the same for these related products. Maybe it doesn't even make sense and there's a better way to do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Beyond the like and full text search (both have limitations either performance and / or flexibility-wise) mysql does not offer other built-in text searching functionality. Anything more advanced than these, you need to create yourself - just use a programming language that does have richer features for searching in text.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want using `LIKE`:

```
where title like '%iPhone X%'
```

If you want more efficiency, you can use full text search.  However, you need to be careful, because by default "X" would not be included in the index.  So, you need to be careful about the minimum word length and stop words.